# How do I enable 4K/2160p YouTube video playback in VLC on my iMac?

Tags: macos, terminal, youtube, vlc

I watch YouTube videos on VLC media player for the convenience of avoiding ads. However, the best resolution that the VLC media player plays, even for videos that play in 4K/2160p on Safari, is 1080p. How do I get 4K/2160p format YouTube video play at the same resolution in VLC?

---

Currently, I use Terminal to minimize the 'clicks' I have to make to achieve the goal, like:

> $> v [https://www.youtube.com/watch\\?v=TnkdoEZhTbc](https://www.youtube.com/watch%5C%5C?v=TnkdoEZhTbc)

where, v is an alias for:

> $> alias v="open -a vlc"

But, as I said, it reduces the resolution to 1080p.

---

<sub>I added a `\` before '?' in the youtube link because `zsh` requires it. If skipped, `zsh` errs out by saying `zsh: no matches found:...`.</sub>